# php mysql display filtered data in dynamic table based on table field value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named `guestlist1` with the following columns: 
`id(Int4)`, `father(Varchar60)`, `father_going(Int1)`, `mother(Varchar60)`, `mother_going(Int1)`, `child_1(Varchar60)` and `child_1_going(Int1)`.

I need to create html table data loaded dynamically from `guestlist1` table but ONLY THOSE FIELDS where `*_going`=1.

Example: we have a family with 3 persons: David, Alice, Jonathan. After each name there is a number: 1, 0, 1. I need to create a table with the same structure as the original but only include data from fields where column name ending with `_going`=1.

:( Please help!
Thank you wey much!

Tried with select statement:

> $query_guestlist ="SELECT father FROM guestlist WHERE (id=$id and father_going=1) UNION SELECT mother FROM guestlist WHERE (id=$id and mother_going=1) UNION SELECT child_1 from guestlist WHERE (id=$id and child_1_going=1)";

This is OK but includes all fields not just the ones with the column name ending with _going=1. If father is going but mother not, then mother should not be included.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Can you include some php code to show what you've tried so far?  Even just a skeletal script is a good start.

Comment: Tried with select statement:
$query_guestlist ="SELECT `father` FROM `guestlist` WHERE (`id`=$id and `father_going`=1) UNION 
SELECT `mother` FROM `guestlist` WHERE (`id`=$id and `mother_going`=1) UNION 
SELECT `child_1` from `guestlist` WHERE (`id`=$id and `child_1_going`=1)";
This is OK but includes all fileds not just the ones with `*_going`=1.
If father is going but mother not then mother should not be included.

Comment: Great!  But that should go into the question as an edit, not as a comment.  Click on the "edit" button below your question and put that comment in there.

Comment: what exactly you mean by *_going ? its any one going=1 OR its all going=1 ??

Comment: By *_going I mean father_going or mother_going or child_1_going :)